# regex syntax for % percentage

Tags: php, regex

Regex issue. Need to replace img.msg.yahoo.com/avatar.php? with www.sitename.com/rproxy?url=img.msg.yahoo.com/avatar.php%3f

```
%VAR-Comments-data.regex("/img.msg.yahoo.com\/avatar.php\?/", "www.sitename.com/rproxy?url=img.msg.yahoo.com/avatar.php[\x25]/'")%
```

Comment: that doesnt look like PHP....

Comment: @prodigitalson I'm guessing this comes from some sort of templating engine.

Comment: When writing a regular expression, (1) figure out what you want it to match, (2) escape special characters with `\ `, (3) escape all backslashes used in a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to escape the dots in the URL:

```
%VAR-Comments-data.regex("/img\.msg\.yahoo\.com\/avatar\.php\?/", "www.sitename.com/rp
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the backslashes in the string. `"/\\./"` is a regex escaped `.` character.

Comment: You can use `preg_quote` to escape everything that needs to be escaped.